# Pegar apenas um valor repetido no mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Galera, eu tenho uma tabela e nela um campo chamado `cargo` sendo que valor dele pode se repetir, como por exemplo, o cargo professor. No meu `HTML` eu estou montando um `<select>` quando recupero o valor desse campo, só que devido o valor dele se repetir ele mostra várias vezes a palavra professor ou qualquer outro que venha a se repetir no na tabela, lógico. Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de "filtrar" e extrair apenas um valor desses repetidos?

Comment: A solução seria normalizar essa tabela, uma tabela para cargos e outra para funcionarios, o campo `cargo`(descrição) não fica na tabela funcionarios, somente seu id(`id_cargo`). POR FAVOR NÃO USE `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @rray por que não posso usar o DISTINCT?

Comment: Não resolve o problema, apenas mascara ele. Já imaginou o que acontece quando o último estagiario for promovido ou demitido? esse cargo ainda estará disponível no combo? Edite a pergunta e coloque a estrutura dessa tabela.

Comment: O ideal seria segmentar em 2 tabelas, conforme o rray comentou. Uma tabela onde estarão os dados do cargo e outra com os dados do funcionário, sendo que, um funcionário deverá conter um cargo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois métodos:

**1. Seria utilizando DISTINCT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cargo) FROM tabela
```

**2. Seria utilizando o GROUP BY:**

```
SELECT cargo FROM tabela GROUP BY cargo
```

Teste isto [clicando aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/140cad/1/0)!

Ambos os métodos possuem o mesmo resultado, como pode ser visualizado, não há muito o que explicar. A função do `Group By` é agrupar por igualdade, resumindo irá exibir uma das duplicações, sendo assim não será mais uma duplicação. =D

Comment: não entendi porque os down votes...

Comment: Também não. Na verdade até achei que era uma coisa que tinha colocado (ver edições) mas enfim. Pelo menos o  autor da publicação aprovou e aparentemente serviu.

Comment: Foi explicado que, nesse caso, o distinct não é a melhor opção. A melhor opção é normalizar a tabela! Trabalhe com foreign keys, distinct nesse caso, é gambiarra! O primeiro comentário feito na pergunta, mostra como deve ser feito.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT cargo FROM `tabela` GROUP BY `tabela`.`cargo` =`cargo`;
```

Dessa forma, forço os resultados onde o meu campo for igual ao campo que pretendo trazendo apenas um resultado, mais o ideal é utilizar a normalização como dito anteriormente.